# JSP and response entities

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jsp, response

I am calling an endpoint from jsp:

```
@GET
@Path("/select-users")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public ResultSet selectUsers() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = appService.connect().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    return result;
}
```

which returns object type `ResultSet`.

From `.jsp` I want to save the response in that object in order to parse the results of the query.

```
<%
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/StudentsCRM/rest/controller/select-users");
ClientResponse myresponse = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);

ResultSet rs = myresponse.getEntity(java.sql.ResultSet.class);

%>
```

**ERROR**: `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.sql.ResultSet, and Java type interface java.sql.ResultSet, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found`

**Question**: Is this the right way to save the ResultSet response?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code:

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public ResultSet selectUsers() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = appService.connect().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    return result;
}
```

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html)

> Produces annotation defines the media type(s) that the methods of a
> resource class or MessageBodyWriter can produce.

You declare, that it produces plain text. But your method does NOT return plain text. It returns `ResultSet`. I think you don't need plain text. You need some data format that can keep users, for example, `JSON` or `XML`.

If you choose JSON, then you should iterate your result set to get a list of users, and return it. Besides, you will need to set correct Produces type.